# Java : How can I configure logger email specific types of log once daily

Tags: java, email, logging

I have been handed over a set of services which basically stays up all time written by other team members . My job is to extend them with some monitoring capabilities like email once daily about any errors or crashes. I have explored all of codes of my services and found they have logging implemented (like logs with `error` level). I am trying configuring my logger emailing only ERROR LEVEL logs but only `ONCE` `one email daily` stating all ERROR LEVEL logs happended for the day
Can I achieve this only with my logger configuration changes only email daily once?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use apache log4j and throw all the logs in the single file.

use smtp of java and take that file as input and send an email and make sure that code works only once in a day by setting up the timer.

Comment: Hi @Pavan: any tools regarding parsing log files!

Comment: @MD.MohiuddinAhmed I don't have any idea on that.

Comment: @MD.MohiuddinAhmed What exactly you need here ?